# Detach and append on checkbox selection, using array built from variables of element ids

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, append, detach

Detach is working fine but not append.  I thought the array was building right but when appending again, array is undefined.  Also, I will need to keep from adding the same element to the array if unchecked multiple times.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ud2opLxx/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var restoreMe = [];
 $("#studentCourses :checkbox").change(function() {

    var courseid = $(this).attr('id'),
        row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        cell = row.children('td').eq(3),
        course = cell.find('input');

    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        //var rm = $.grep(restoreMe, function(e){ return e.courseid.to_string == courseid.to_string; });
        row.css('color', '#000000');
        restoreMe[courseid].appendTo( cell ); 
        //rm[0].courseid.appendTo( cell ); 
    } else {
        row.css('color', '#c0c0c0');
        restoreMe.push({courseid: course.detach()});
        }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restoreMe.push({courseid: course.detach()});` adds a new dictionary to the list, not a new entry to the dictionary.

Change it to `restoreMe[courseid] = course.detach();` as it works as expected.

Comment: That's precisely what I did in the JSFiddle, just before you posted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental problem with your code, which is that `restoreMe` is an array instead of a JavaScript object. Making it an array makes it difficult to search for the items (you need to loop through), and there is also a possibility to make duplicate entries (since there is no check on key).

Objects, however, can be constructed as key-value pairs, making keys unique throughout the object. Since you have unique IDs for those elements, making entries in an object and retrieving from it will be far easier.

Here are the parts which I've changed in your code:

```
...

var restoreMe = {};

...

restoreMe[courseid].appendTo( cell ); 

...

restoreMe[courseid] = course.detach();
```

And, lastly, checkout this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2d75r4Lr/1/).

Comment: lightning fast response!  Thank you.  I too tried building the array this way and then noticed your reply.  Its working now but I didn't have to swap square brackets for curly braces.  restoreMe=[] worked fine with restoreMe[coursed] = course.detach();

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the array push and it works now:
restoreMe[courseid] = course.detach();